# Find the expected value of $(X^2+Y^2)/(XY)$ whwre $X,Y$ are independent geometric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent Geometric(p) random variables. Find $E[(X^2+Y^2)/(XY)]$.

I am really struggling with this question because I want to apply the LOTUS equation but am unsure how to do it for geometric variables. Any help would be appreciated.

*Geometric distribution understood as: number of trials until first success*

Comment: Start by simplying the expression within the expectation and using the fact that the expectation is linear (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

Comment: How $\frac{X^2+Y^2}{XY}$ is defined when both $X$ and $Y$ equal zero?

Comment: $=E(X/Y+Y/X)=2E(X/Y)=2E(X)E(1/Y)=\frac 2 p\sum_{i\geq 1}\frac 1 ip(1-p)^{i-1}=\frac 2 p \frac p {1-p}\log \frac 1 p=\frac 2 {1-p} \log \frac 1 p$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio There are two distributions called geometric, the distribution of *trials until success* and that of *failures before success*.  The former is supported over $\{1,...,\infty\}$

Answer (score 1):

We want the expectation of $\frac{Y}{X}+\frac{X}{Y}$, which by linearity is the expectation of $Y/X$ plus the expectation of $X/Y$.
By independence, we have $E(Y/X)=E(Y)E(1/X)$. We know $E(Y)$ so all we need is $E(1/X)$.

For the expectation of $1/X$, we want the sum
$$p\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k}q^{k-1},\tag{1}$$
where $q=1-p$.

Recall that the Maclaurin series of $-\ln(1-x)$ is
$$x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots.$$
Now looking at (1) we see that
$$E(1/X)=-\frac{p}{q}\ln p.$$
Now put the pieces together. You should get something like $\frac{2}{q}\ln(1/p)$. (I rewrote $-\ln p$ as $\ln(1/p)$ in order to avoid minus signs.)